Is this screw inside a 2-prong receptacle a possible ground?
My house was built in the 1920s and I don't know how old this wall box is. Is there any hope that the bottom screw is a ground? If not, what are the metal circles for?


Almost assuredly not.  To my untrained eye, that looks like knob-and-tube individual wires coming into that box.  In addition to the very low chance of those actually being grounded, there's not a valid way to attach to those open knockouts from previous wires that would have come into the same box.  In addition, those remaining wires that are visible are way too short to make any new connections safely, especially since it looks like any connections would need to be made deep in the box rather than having enough wire to correctly tighten the wirenuts outside the box with enough insulation to completely protect the connections.

I'm pretty sure if you got a vintage 1920s switch you could make the connection safely (with the power turned off while you wire it up). Knob and tube is safer than modern wiring but it's labor intensive and the know-how to actually work on it is all but lost. There's a reason why there's no ground. It is very difficult otherwise to keep the constraint that knob and tube has; it will not short even after the insulation is gone.

Do you have any references to indicate that K&T without ground is safer than modern wiring with a ground?  There is a reason all modern wiring standards require a ground wire and that is for user safety.

This is family history to me. The wiring routing is the hot and the neutral are on opposite sides of the room. This is the switch control box; there's no neutral anywhere near it. Trying to add a ground here brings a ground close to the hot where it would otherwise be feet away, actually increasing the risk of incident.

The problem with keeping the feet-separation between hot and neutral becomes apparent when there's more than one outlet per wall. Draw the wiring diagrams out and try to route the wires so that the principle is maintained so that the two wires diverge from the outlet in opposite directions and no hot can ever drop on a neutral or the other way around.

And once you have succeeded, try to add the ground wires without breaking the principle. There's no way to do it unless your ground wires are rated enough to act as the neutral return for the entire house.

How often do wires in modern wiring requirements get crossed with damaged insulation, compared to the number of people who get shocked because there is no safety ground?  If ground isn't important, why is it a requirement now?  By your logic, there's no justification for a safety ground because in K&T, wires are farther apart.  This has no impact on miswired or faulty appliances or other devices that get plugged into a wall outlet.   The next time you go to rewire a house go ahead and use K&T, try and get your electrical inspector to pass your electrical without ground, "because it's safer".

If I could find two wire GFCIs for sale I probably could; but it isn't safe to wire a modern house with knob and tube because of slab foundations. I can get two wire versions of almost any electronic device a house needs. The kitchen still needs ground wires so appliances aren't an issue.

The metal circles are knockouts, for wire entry at the other end of the box, just like the knockouts where the two existing wires enter the box.
It's difficult to see the screw you're pointing at, but I believe it's for a clamp to hold the wires coming through the knockout(s).
Could that screw (or the hole it's in) be used for grounding?  Yes, but.

If you had a ground wire coming in to the box, that you wanted to use to ground the box, then yes, with the right screw, you could make a good connection to the box.  (But I'm guessing that's not what you're trying to do.)

If you wanted to add a ground wire coming out of the box, on the other hand, that's a different story. For example, if you were planning on installing a grounded receptacle in this box, and you wanted to connect a proper grounding pigtail between the receptacle and the box, then the question is, is the box already grounded, and the answer is, almost certainly not.


As far as I know, pretty much nobody was grounding anything in the 1920's.  Trying to retrofit grounded outlets into wiring that old is a pretty famously difficult/impossible problem.
Needless to say, trying to do anything with wiring that old — it's a hundred years old! — is a dicey and generally a losing proposition.  Antique knob-and-tube wiring isn't necessarily insanely dangerous, as long as it's not disturbed.  But here you've got antique knob-and-tube wiring that has been disturbed, and I'd be seriously thinking about replacing it pronto.
